# TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, ajax, httpresponse

When I click on like button then I get internal server error in console.

The main problem is in returning a HttpResponse from view function . How to  return value in **HttpResponse** so that I can access in javascripts??

Console error:

> jquery.js:9837 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/post/like/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Views :

```
    class PostLikeView(generic.View):
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.user
            post_id = request.POST['post_id']
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            user_liked, created = PostLike.objects.get_or_create(post=post, user=user)
            if not created:
                PostLike.objects.filter(post=post).filter(user=user).delete()
                total = post.like.count
                data = {'total-like':total,'user_liked':False}
            else :
                total = post.like.count
                data = {'total-like':total,'user_liked':True}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
            

javaScripts :

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('.likebutton').click(function(){ 
        var id; 
        id = $(this).attr("data-catid"); 
        $.ajax( 
        { 
            type:"POST", 
            url: "blogs/post/like/", 
            data:{ csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                     post_id: id 
                 },
            dataType: 'json', 
          });
          //(function(data){
            //data = JSON.parse(data)
            //console.log(data)
         // });
           });
        </script>
```

Errors got in terminal :

```
    Internal Server Error: /blogs/post/like/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\publish\studentcollegeworld\blogs\views.py", line 114, in post
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
      File "c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
        return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
      File "c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
        raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable
    [25/May/2020 17:14:55] "POST /blogs/post/like/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20260
```

Comment: You need `total = post.like.count()` I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG yahh  thanx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a parenthesis after the post.like.count in both places.
It should be `total = post.like.count()` in the if and else blocks.